# Does use of unnamed namespaces reduce link time?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a large system with many object files such that link time is a problem.  Suppose also that I know that many of the classes and functions in my system are not used outside their translation unit.

1. Is it reasonable to assume that if I reduce the number of symbols with external linkage, my link-time will be reduced?
2. If so, will putting the entities (e.g., classes and functions) that are used in only a single TU into unnamed namespaces do me any good?  Technically, the entities with external linkage will retain their external linkage in an unnamed namespace, but, as the C++11 standard notes,

> Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage, they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit.

Do linker algorithms perform optimizations based on the knowledge that entities with external linkage in unnamed namespaces aren't visible outside their namespaces?

Comment: Maybe you can do some benchmarks and let us know the results? (my guess is that it won't help, but that's just a guess).

Comment: Wouldn't limiting the scope and avoiding collisions (specifically namespace pollution) be good enough reasons to use anonymous namespaces liberally?

Comment: @delnan: Maybe, but that's not the question.  Suppose I have a big legacy system where unnamed namespaces were not used, and I'm looking for a way to reduce the link time involving that system.  Would adding unnamed namespaces be a reasonable way to invest my time and effort if my goal is to reduce link time?

Comment: You do realize that this behaviour would be obviously very platform and compiler dependent, right? So telling us what compiler you use might be a good idea if you want to actually get answers (I doubt it would help, because few people would know this and it isn't exactly easy to test, but still). Personally I doubt change the linktime much, but thats jsut a guess.

Comment: @Grizzly: It's not obvious to me that it's necessarily platform-dependent.  For all I know, it's a common optimization.  I'm fairly certain that link-time is in some way proportional to the number of symbols the linker has to deal with, so if it can dismiss large numbers of external symbols by noting that they are essentially internal, I'd expect that to positively affect link time.  Anyway, my question is general.  I'm not trying to solve a particular problem on a particular platform, I'm trying to better understand the utility of unnamed namespaces.

Answer (score 6):

Yes I think is does reduce the link time. I think this on the Google chromium stie: 
"Unnamed namespaces restrict these symbols to the compilation unit, improving function call cost and reducing the size of entry point tables." [Here](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/coding-style#TOC-Unnamed-Namespaces) the link

I know this is about the chromium project but it should apply to other c++ projects.

Comment: The linked doc seems to be talking specifically about dynamic linking, but that may still have an effect on the OP's problem...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how a linker could do such optimizations, because by the time the linker gets a hold of the symbol(s) in question they look like ordinary decorated external-linkage symbols. Unless the linker has specific information about how the compiler decorates names in an anonymous namespace I can't see any way that it could optimize its work.

Have you confirmed that your linker is in fact CPU bound and not I/O bound? If it's not CPU bound already it's probably not going to help to reorganize your code.

Comment: My guess is that it would be the *compiler* that might "optimise" the object files it outputs by omitting symbols from unnamed namespaces.  This would presumably leave the linker with less work to do.

Comment: Seems to me it would be trivial for the compiler to skip putting the symbols in the object file in the first place. Shrinking the number of symbols would certainly help even if it were I/O bound.

Comment: @MarkRansom: You would think so, but C++ being C++ it wouldn't surprise me if there's a corner case somewhere that defies this nice clean rule...